# WSO2 Custom Handlers in a Cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In a cluster, where does WSO2 APIM store the configuration files that, in a non-clustered deployment are kept under:

```
<wso2_home>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api
```

I published a Ticket API through Publisher in a clustered deployment of WSO2 but haven't found the corresponding 'admin--TicketAPI_v1.0.xml' file anywhere. The clustering guide creates several databases. Would this xml file be stored in any of the WSO2 databases? If so, where? What I need to do is to add Custom Handlers to my API by adding to the "handlers" section of the 'admin--TicketAPI_v1.0.xml' file, as explained in the [Writing Custom Handlers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Writing+Custom+Handlers) doc. How is this accomplished in a clustered deployment?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find admin--TicketAPI_v1.0.xml file in your gateway node

/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api

Answer (score 0):

Your admin--TicketAPI_v1.0.xml file should be there in one of the gateway worker nodes.

However, It is not recommended to update the API source code via the source view UI or file system when engaging a custom handler to selected APIs, because the customizations get overridden by the publisher updates.

So the recommended way is to add the custom handler that you wrote to the velocity_template.xml found in /repository/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml

Comment: Much appreciated. Yes, after some digging, our team figured this out. Good to know that this is the recommended approach. Thanks!